# Recover git files created and deleted in a single commit

Tags: git, recover

I've made a huge beginner mistakes while using git.
I created several python files, then deleted them accidently, and then commited.
So now the files aren't there anymore but they're unknown to git because they didn't exist in the last commit.

Is there a way to retrieve them ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What commands did you run? If you've removed the files before adding them using `git add` you've most likely lost the work.

Comment: I dit remove them before using git add. I don't really know how the git tree works but maybe there is some linux command to retrive them ?

Comment: Some IDEs have a local history in addition to any VCS (like git). For example IntelliJ IDEA might be able to restore the files if they were inside of a project directory.

Answer (score 3):

In short: No, you can not retrieve the files.

As you describe it, there is no "git" way to retrieve them. Only when files have been added and commited using `git add` and `git commit`, git knows about the files.
Git also keeps track of a state of a file if you stashed it, but I don't think you did that.

Git is not "running in the background" and tracking everything that happens in the directory. You need to invoke specific commands to interact with git.

Comment: Slight correction: it's sometimes possible to get back files that where `git add`ed but not `git commit`ed. However, if no `git add` ever happened then your answer is 100% correct: git never saw those files.